# Errno 13: Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\myname\\.aws' when running command: AWS Configure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` set to `C:\Users\myname\.aws`

When I run command `aws configure` and pass in the correct details I get the below error:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\myname.aws'

And a `credentials` file has appeared in folder `C:\Users\myname\.aws`

But, when I run the command `aws configure` again, the `AWS Access Key ID` and `AWS Secret Access Key` are already set, but the `Default Region Name` and `Default Output Format` are `[None]`.

**Question 1:**: Why hasn't the `config` file been created?

Then, when I run command `aws s3 ls` I get error:

> An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

**Question 2:** Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you confirm the value of `AWS_CONFIG_FILE`? The first error message you provided is missing a backslash

Answer (score 0):

It worked with me after deleting the credentials inside .aws and trying again. As per the recommendation [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3032).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other solutions to no avail. The only way to get it to work was to manually create the 2 files required - config with content like this:

```
[default]
region=ap-southeast-2
output=json

and credentials like this:
[default]
aws_access_key_id=YOURKEY
aws_secret_access_key=YOURSECRETKEY
```

On Windows the files go into C:\Users\Username\.aws and neither file has an extension. Afterwards you can confirm it with

```
aws configure list
```

on the commandline. Hopes this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows.
The AWS docs say to set env var AWS_CONFIG_FILE.
I set it to a local path where I wanted my config file to go:
set AWS_CONFIG_FILE=C:\MyName\aws\config\config.txt
But the "aws configure" command keeps giving me:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\MyName\aws\config'
After reading several articles about Errno 13, I tried
set AWS_CONFIG_FILE=C:\MyName\aws\config\config.txt.
Upon adding the double backslash, the aws config command worked!